# How to stop Bash from going into the next loop iteration until the current process finishes?

Tags: java, bash, for-loop

I have a Bash script that goes something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

    for i in $(seq 1 100); do
     nohup java -jar myProgram.jar -myParameter1 input$i -myParameter2 $i > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    done
```

The Java program (myProgram.jar) prints a lot of output to the stderr and stdout that I don't need and also takes at least 10 minutes to run, so I want to be able to log off from the remote computer and have it keep going for hours (thus, I use `nohup` and redirect stdout and stderr to `/dev/null` with `2>&1`).

However, if I run this script as it is, it will just keep running the programs one on top of the other until it runs out of memory/processors (I suppose) and then it runs the next program once one of them finishes. I wouldn't mind this happening but it is a shared server so I cannot slow it down for several hours. Is there a way to prevent Bash from going onto the next loop iteration until the current myProgram is finished running?

Comment: Remove `&` from end of your command line.

Comment: Don't run the process in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `&` from end of your command line to make it run in foreground. With `&` at end of line  you are forcing your program to run in background in the loop.